# How to solve a system of linear equations using substitution or elimination

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm supposed to be using the substitution or elimination technique to solve

\begin{align*}
x + 2y & = 11\\
x - y & = -1 
\end{align*}

but for some odd reason I continue getting the wrong answer. For some odd reason I keep getting a graph answer for these, and I know that is wrong since I need to show step-by-step solution. If anyone could kindly help me with these equations, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Multiply the second equation by $2$ and then sum them both together to solve for $x$.

Comment: You should get $x=3, $y=4$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you keep getting a "graph answer"? Could you explain what you did?

Comment: @JackM I'd guess he means he gets the answer by plotting both functions.

Comment: Yes, at @YoTengoUnLCD

Answer (score 2):

$$
x-y=-1\implies x=y-1\\
\Downarrow\\
x+2y=11\Longleftrightarrow (y-1)+2y=11\Longleftrightarrow 3y=12\Longleftrightarrow y=4\\
\Downarrow\\
x-y=-1\Longleftrightarrow x-4=-1\Longleftrightarrow x=3
$$

Answer (score 1):

The method MagicMan showed you is called *substitution*.

You can also use *elimination*.

\begin{align*}
x + 2y & = 11 \tag{1}\\
x - y & = -1 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Subtract equation 2 from equation 1 to obtain
\begin{align*}
3y & = 12\\
y & = 4
\end{align*}
Now substitute $4$ for $y$ in equation 1 to obtain
\begin{align*}
x + 2 \cdot 4 & = 11\\
x + 8 & = 11\\
x & = 3
\end{align*}
The solution is $(3, 4)$.  You can verify this by substituting $3$ for $x$ and $4$ for $y$ in equations $1$ and $2$.  It represents the points where the graphs of the lines $x + 2y = 11$ and $x - y = -1$ intersect.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Subtracting the second equation from the first gives $3y=12$ while the first plus 2 times the second equation would give $3x=9$ which would be using the elimination method. Are you getting to this point?